# Foreign Key After Table Creation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have already created a table in MySQL! And have tried a number of queries to alter the table and add foreign key to the table!
But none of them work?? 
No error message no nothing but still nothing happening...

I need the exact query which would work! :(

Details:

1. Table1: **users** column: **id**
2. Table2: **Pokemon_ref** column: **pkmn_id**

If an insertion is done in Table1 then it should also be added in Table2!

Comment: hey please upload the query and the error message

Comment: your first change the table to InnoDB and then try it.  for more reference link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818759/what-is-innodb-and-myisam-in-mysql

Comment: Its working now :) thnks anyways

Comment: "*then it should also be added in Table2*" - this is not how foreign keys work. The prevent insertion with values that do not match a valid value in the referenced table. A foreign key will **never** "add" rows automatically to a table.

Comment: I meant if a user registers at #50 as id in table1, the table2 will also be updated id=50 ..

Comment: this should happen with foreign key .. i think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Name_ID FOREIGN KEY (fk_ID)
    REFERENCES (R_id);
```

***https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html***

***http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp***

***[Alter table to give foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471348/alter-table-to-give-foreign-key-constraint)***

Answer (score 1):

```
    category INT NOT NULL, id INT NOT NULL,
    price DECIMAL,
    PRIMARY KEY(category, id)
)   ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE customer (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)   ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE product_order (
    no INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    product_category INT NOT NULL,
    product_id INT NOT NULL,
    customer_id INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(no),
    INDEX (product_category, product_id),
    INDEX (customer_id),

    FOREIGN KEY (product_category, product_id)
      REFERENCES product(category, id)
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,

    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
      REFERENCES customer(id)
)
```

Comment: ALTER TABLE tabl2
ADD COLUMN FOREIGNID INT NOT NULL,
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FOREIGNID) REFERENCES tabl1(ID)